# Symfony 3.1 custom bundle doctrine crud generation creates views in default resources folder

Tags: templates, view, symfony-3.1

I am using symfony 3.1 for development. I have created a new bundle using symfony bundle generator. And created a User entity using symfony console app. Till now everything is great.

When i create crud using doctrine for User entity, It created all structure including controller, usertype, correctly, except views for user entity, **user** folder for views is created in default app/Resources/views instead of CustomBundle/Resources/views.

Why this is happening ? And if i copy the **users** view directory to my CustomBundle/Resources/view it throws error.

**Error:**

Unable to find template "user/index.html.twig" (looked into: /var/www/html/sym/app/Resources/views, /var/www/html/sym/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form).

Answer (score 0):

In your UserController try to replace path to template (example for users list template)

```
    return $this->render('user/index.html.twig', array(
        'users' => $users,
    ));
```

by full path with YourBundle name

```
    return $this->render('CustomBundle:user:index.html.twig', array(
        'users' => $users,
    ));
```